# Converting c++ array and pointers to C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, .net, pointers

I want to know how to convert the below snipped (c++) into C#. The issue is the c++ code is using pointer notations and not sure what is the equivalent in c#.

Tried different syntax to convert the c++ code into C#, not completely successful.

```
void DataExtractor::runM1(unsigned char* slice, unsigned short* frame, int nALines, int nHeight)
{
         if (!slice)
         {
            return;
         }
    
        // Apply 
        unsigned char* p1 = slice;
        for (int k = nHeight - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            int nRow = (B_FLIP ? k : (nHeight - 1 - k));
    
            // Reverse order
            unsigned short* p2 = frame + nALines * nRow;
    
            unsigned short* p2End = p2 + nALines;
            for (; p2 < p2End;)
            {
                unsigned short M1 = unsigned short((NEW_MAX - NEW_MIN + 1) / 256.0)* *p1++ + NEW_MIN;
                if (M1 < 256)
                {
                    M1 = 256;
                }
                *p2++ = M1;
            }
        }
 }
```

The calling sequence is like this  :

================================

```
DataExtractor* fdsDataExtract = new DataExtractor();
unsigned short** inputVol = new unsigned short*[nFrames];
float** preTopQVol = new float*[nFrames];

inputVol[iFrame] = new unsigned short[nALines*nHeight];
preTopQVol[iFrame] = new float[nALines*nHeight];

// Read Image Frame
unsigned char* slice = scanImage[iFrame];

//-----------------------------------

dataExtractor->uncompressImg(slice, inputVol[iFrame], nALines, nHeight);

//----------------------------------

DataExtractor* fdsDataExtract = new DataExtractor();
unsigned short** inputVol = new unsigned short*[nFrames];
float** preTopQVol = new float*[nFrames];

inputVol[iFrame] = new unsigned short[nALines*nHeight];
preTopQVol[iFrame] = new float[nALines*nHeight];

// Read Image Frame
unsigned char* slice = scanImage[iFrame];

//-----------------------------------

dataExtractor->uncompressImg(slice, inputVol[iFrame], nALines, nHeight);

//----------------------------------


DataExtractor.cpp
=====================

#include "DataExtractor.h"

#define B_FLIP 0
#define NEW_MIN 0
#define NEW_MAX 65535

void DataExtractor::uncompressImg(unsigned char * slice, unsigned short * inputImg, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    runM1(slice, inputImg, nWidth, nHeight);
}



void DataExtractor::runM1(unsigned char* slice, unsigned short* frame, int nALines, int nHeight)
{
    if (!slice)
    {
        return;
}

// Apply 
unsigned char* p1 = slice;
for (int k = nHeight - 1; k >= 0; k--)
{
    int nRow = (B_FLIP ? k : (nHeight - 1 - k));

    // Reverse order
    unsigned short* p2 = frame + nALines * nRow;

    unsigned short* p2End = p2 + nALines;
    for (; p2 < p2End;)
    {
        unsigned short M1 = unsigned short((NEW_MAX - NEW_MIN + 1) / 256.0)* *p1++ + NEW_MIN;
        if (M1 < 256)
        {
            M1 = 256;
        }
        *p2++ = M1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointers can be used in `IntPtr` type.

Comment: I figure you want to have the same _functionality_ in C# as you have in C++, right? If so, don't bother "translating" the code. Write down the _requirements_ and then implement those in C#. There is not exactly an equivalent in managed, safe C# code. So, basically it's "do it the C# way" - at first glance, you'd probably want to use arrays and respective indexes if not even "higher" collection types.